# iOS attach an UIImageView to an email

Tags: ios, uiimageview, email-attachments

I am working on an app that will send information to an email. I have a button that when you press it brings up the choice of an image from the library or from the camera. Once the image is selected it then shows it in a UIImageView. How do I attach that image then from the UIImageView into the email once the "Send Report' Button has been pressed?

Here is the code i've tried using to load:

```
// Attach an image to the email.
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];
```

However I can't work out how to attach my image from my UIImageView. The UIImageView is called imageView.

Comment: Without knowing more about what you are using to send emails and what your code looks like there is no way we can truly help you. The only answer I can possibly offer is that if you have an email class, you could give it a property called emailImage or imageAttachment and then place your image in the property before sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([imageView image]);
[picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

It has method `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`.  So you need to get your image as NSData.

Comment: This is what I thought might do it but it seems to want me to create a new image rather than adding the UIImageView.

Comment: Just use the UIImageView's image property. That's what is holding the image anyways. imageView.image